# iOS - initialize object from weak reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, weak-references

I have an object **Main_Obj** in Class A, which is a strong property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableDictionary *Main_Obj;
```

i am creating another property in another Class B pointing to this strong reference.

```
@property(nonatomic, weak)NSMutableDictionary *weak_Obj;

weak_obj =  Main_Obj;
```

Using weak reference in Class B I have to create the `Main_Obj` in Class A **IF** `Main_Obj` is nil.

But the problem is, i only have a weak reference `weak_obj` pointing to a strong reference 'Main_Obj' which is currently nil. How can i initialize `Main_Obj` from Class B which have only weak reference (currently nil).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: I did some improvements can u understand it now?

Comment: can't get your question.. Please explain more.

Comment: Are you talking something like: 

  ClassA * a = [[ClassA alloc]init]; // nothing is actually initialise;;
  ClassB * b = [[ClassB alloc]init];
  a.Main_Obj = b.weak_Obj;

Comment: Show where you set `Main_Obj`.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming only Class A and B are in your project)

Since **Class B** has a strong reference it is the one who should be responsible for creating (and releasing) the allocated dictionary object.

**Class A** has a weak reference and should only be assigned a valid (or nil) value to that weak reference.

You can have a listener in **class B** (in this case it would be class A). Once the dictionary object is created by **Class B** notify the listener with the created instance.